# Where is InputFile in Blazor and Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

As I understand it, with .NET 5 in Blazor I should be able to use InputFile. I don't have that option. I am on VS 16.8, I have the .net 5 SDK installed, in a  Blazor Web Assembly project (using .Net Standard 2.1), with .Net Core Hosted (using .Net 5) but InputFile is not recognized as valid syntax. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates for visual studio havent been updated so its still targets .NET standard rather than .NET 5. Use this guide https://www.davideguida.com/how-to-migrate-blazor-webassembly-to-net-5/

Comment: Also remove the razor language line, I couldnt get multiple files to work with it still in.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should just "work" in a .razor file (assuming you are targetting `net5.0`). i'm using it in a Blazor Server app without any extra `using` statements. it's part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms namespace

```
@page "/"
@using server.Data //this is specific to my app
@using server.Data.Util //this too
@inject IJSRuntime js //this is just the js interop

...

<InputFile OnChange="@HandleFileSelectedAsync" />

<section>
    @if (_uploading)
    {
        <p>Uploading...</p>
        <div class="loader"></div>
    }
...
```

UPDATE: i also noticed i had a `_Imports.razor` file in my project that must have gotten created by VisualStudio when i made a new project. it looks like this:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms //InputFile in here
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
...
```

Comment: It should just work in the same way a InputSelect works, but it's not there...

Comment: does your csproj reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`? this necessary when porting to `net5.0` (so now it is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">`)

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestion by Mario that the Blazor app should be targeting .net 5.0, I went to the project properties and found that it was targeting .net core 3.1 by default.

Changing the target to .net 5.0 made it work.

Thank you!